# How to get value mapping from sklearn Leave One Out encoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, leave-one-out

I am using the `LeaveOneOutEncoder` from [category_encoders](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/leaveoneout.html). I am able to encode my data.

How to get a map of the original value and looe_value pair?

Original:

| city | salary |
| --- | --- |
| san jose | 120 |
| san jose | 100 |
| austin | 95 |

Encoded:

| city | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 110 | 120 |
| 110 | 100 |
| 95 | 95 |

I want to have a map of `city_sanjose = 110; city_austin = 95`. How to create this map? Do I have to do it manually?

Comment: `self.mapping`?

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code?